# dropbox python api import dropbox syntax error

Tags: python, dropbox

Using Python 2.6.6

Trying to install dropbox python api..

Tried both ' pip install dropbox ' and ' python setup.py install '

Got this error... on import dropbox

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dropbox/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import client, rest, session
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dropbox/client.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .rest import ErrorResponse, RESTClient, params_to_urlencoded
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dropbox/rest.py", line 415
    utf8_params = {encode(k): encode(v) for k, v in params.iteritems()}
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

am i doing anything wrong..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the code in the dropbox API uses [dictionary comprehensions](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), which were not introduced until Python 2.7.  This can also be seen on [the PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dropbox) for this module, which lists 2.7 as the Python version needed.  You will not be able to use this module unless you upgrade to Python 2.7.  (According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813049/dropbox-api-request-token-not-working-with-python-3) it must be Python 2.7, as the API doesn't yet support Python 3.)

Comment: Thanks a ton! That's the issue.. Installed and checked with python 2.7.3 its working fine.